# Javascript visibility slow on sub elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, dom

I have used javascript style to imitate a pop-up box(any other idea would be appreciated). I have a function to set it visible or hidden based on some conditions.
I have two buttons on the pop up box ,"close": which closes the popup and sets it as hidden and "save": which saves whatever was on the pop up box.
My function only tells the box to close when i want it to. It does this right. But it takes about 4 seconds for both buttons to be hidden(which is not acceptable). and so i tried to invoke another function that hides both buttons as soon as the box is hidden, but this 4 second interval is still there and i have no idea why.

JAVASCRIPT

```
function login(showhide) {
        if (showhide == "show") {
            document.getElementById('popuplogin').style.visibility = "visible";
        } else if (showhide == "hide") {
            document.getElementById('popuplogin').style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
        document.getElementById("container1").style.filter = "blur";
    }
```

HTML

```
 <div id ="popuplogin">
       <form class ="loginform">
           <div class ="backbutton2" onclick="login('hide')"></div>
           <input type ="text" placeholder ="Name" id ="loginname" class="boxes" />
           <input type="password" placeholder ="Password" id ="loginpassword" class="boxes"/>
           <p class ="btn1" onclick ="logger()">LOG IN</p>
           </form>
       </div>
```

Comment: You should run the timeline in a web browser developer tools window like firefox or safari and identify which part of load time is taking so long because it could be the result of other scripts executing before this.

Comment: My guess is there is some other code you are not showing that is causing the issue.... Are you making a synchronous Ajax call or running a loop of some sort?

Comment: I'm not even using ajax. No loop is supposed to execute around that block. @MiiinimalLogic I'm using visual studio for a windows application. Nothing web related